# Is it possible to increase the brightness (light) only in specific area of the display?

Tags: windows-7, fedora, desktop, brightness

I have Lenovo T460, I use to listen songs (Video songs) while working on other window.

Like this:

[image]

I would like to increase the brightness only for the specific window, in this case the one window which is playing video.

When I say brightness, I meant the amount of light which comes from the display. Not the brightness which comes with the players that would only change the brightness, but not the actual light of the display.

I am wondering if this is possible?

I am using Fedora operating system, I am also open to see if this option available in any of the operating system as well (Windows/Mac/etc).

Comment: For a window playing a video, yes. In general for a specific portion of a display, no.

Comment: @dirkt Could you please explain how? Do you mean for all the application windows, we can increase the brightness? e.g. If I have excel program in one window and in another window I have chrome. I can increase the brightness of Excel window?

Comment: 1) A video application in general will have to decode the frames from some compressed format. Changing brightness during the decoding is often easy, because the decoding will happen in that sort of framework, anyway. Which is why many video playing applications allow you to adjust brightness. 2) Even if the video application didn't do that, many (but not all) hardware accelerated implementations to display video allow it (and sometimes the video player provide controls for this). 3) None of this applies to a random application, e.g. Excel.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust brightness, contrast & gamma in VLC independently of that for your overall screen settings.

[VLC HowTo/Adjust image settings](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Adjust_image_settings/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this but it is basically changing the color (brightness, contrast etc). But not actually increasing the light. Increasing the brightness, I mean, increasing the light (brightness) of a specific window.

Comment: How would you expect that to work? Your screen cannot brighten beyond what the backlight is set to.

Comment: I didn't expect the display to be brighten beyond the limit. What I was asking is to increase the brightness (out of total capacity e.g. 60%) for the window where the video is playing, and for others less brightness. I hope this helps to understand my question.

Comment: Also, I doubt if this is actually possible in today's displays. I just wondered if this is possible in this modern world :).